# Only few users can create MS Flow in tenant and all other users can use the MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, modern-experience, flow, ms-flow

I have a requirement where only few users can create MS Flow in entire tenant, however all other users can use it and initiate/run the flows.

Could you please me know, how it can be achieved in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

For people who can edit/create flows you can use the "Share" button at the top of the ribbon in your flow. To configure users only to run flows, there is a setting called "Run Only Users" where you can add users who can run but not edit.

[image]

What you can do is disable flows at site collection level. Check [this](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=786) reference link. I tried disabling using the below code from the above reference link:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteCollName -Credentials 'xyz1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
Set-PnPSite -DisableFlows:$true
```

This made the flows button disappear from the site collection. But when I login into flow and perform an action on the same site collection, it succeeds.

Comment: I looking for option to stop site owner also to create a new MS flow from any SharePoint List

Comment: Then currently it is not possible to restrict users from creating flows because flow is free.

Comment: Check the updated answer